# Variable always being "0.0"

Tags: java, android, time

This code runs in a loop, but the variable `d` is always "0.0" (tested with breakpoints).

```
private static float startTime;

private boolean attackCore(Canvas canvas, RectF eCastle, float width, float height) {
    if (startTime == -1) startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    randomX = new Random((long) width);
    randomY = new Random((long) height);
    float x2 = randomX.nextFloat() + eCastle.right;
    float y2 = randomY.nextFloat() + eCastle.top;

    double d = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) * 30;

    float[] c = Game.moveTo(x1, y1, x2, y2, d);
    if (d >= sqrt(pow(x1 - x2, 2) + pow(y1 - y2, 2))) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(arrow, x2, y2, null);
        startTime = -1;
        return true;
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(arrow, c[0], c[1], null);
    return false;
}
```

Here's `moveTo` in `Game`:

```
public static float[] moveTo(float xA, float yA, float xB, float yB, double dAC) {
    double dAB = sqrt(pow(xA - xB, 2) + pow(yA - yB, 2));

    float xC = (float) (xA + (xB - xA)*dAC/dAB);
    float yC = (float) (yA + (yB - yA)*dAC/dAB);

    return new float[] {xC, yC};
}
```

I tried making the variable non-static and setting it's value to -1. Also must say that the code is working in another class, so I'm a bit disoriented of where the error is, if you need another part of the code, just ask me.

Comment: Why is `startTime` a `float`?

Comment: if (startTime == -1) startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); why will startTIme will be -1? you didn't initialise it right?

Comment: @Anil to reinitialize it when ever the start time has to be reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you lose precision when you convert `System.currentTimeMillis()` from `long` to `float`.  For values as large as `System.currentTimeMillis()` typically returns, consecutive `float` values are much more widely spaced than integers.

You should have `startTime` as a `long`.  Probably `d` should be a `long` too.  And when you do the division, make sure you do the multiplication before the division, so that the rounding happens as late as possible.

```
long startTime;
// ... assign startTime to whatever it's supposed to be
long d = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) * 30 / 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.currentTimeInMillis()` is a long

(long - long) / int = int
if `currentTime - startTime / 1000`, then `currentTime - startTime<1000 = 0` always

you need to cast them to floats

(float)(currentTime - startTime)/ 1000.f

Comment: `( long - long ) / int = int` ... are you sure?

Comment: If a second passes `1000/1000` then `d` must be 1.0, and it is not!

Comment: when you divide by int, you get an int, the fact that you cast the return value to double, does not mean you will have something after the decimal point